# What is deference between wallet address and account address?

Tags: wallets, accounts

I'm new in Ether world. I want to make mini Crypto exchange site with 2 coin ETH and BTC. What is deference between wallet address(maybe It's called Main Ether address) and account address ? or it's incorrect question ? Please give me right and more details way to understand what's happen. Thank you

Comment: Looks almost identical to https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/68350.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, I think they are the same thing.

From [Mastering Ethereum](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/04keys-addresses.asciidoc#keys-and-addresses):

> Ethereum has two different types of accounts: externally owned accounts (EOAs) and contracts

I think you're just describing 2 EOA's. These are just addresses at which ether can be held.

Comment: Thank you for response, but I'm interested, Exchange must have one wallet and other accounts will create by this main wallet ?

Comment: I suspect there are lots of ways to tackle creating an exchange ;) But you could have a single wallet generate many accounts, yes.

Comment: Can you link me sources ? My I create EOA for all customer?

Answer (score 0):

In ethereum wallet address and account address, both are the same. we commonly say it as wallet address bcoz we import the key pairs(public and private keys) into wallets like metamask or scatter. Now the public will be called as your wallet address as well as ur account address. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, I want to make exchange, how can I create exchange account ? I Image that exchange must has 'main' address and when one my system's user want's to withdraw some ETH to other exchange account, system must transfer coin from 'main' account