# web3.eth.accounts.create vs web3.eth.accounts.wallet.create

Tags: web3js, wallets, accounts, account-generation

I was playing with web3.eth.accounts.create() and web3.eth.accounts.wallet.create functions, and reading [web3 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-accounts.html) about it. I know that an externally-owned account is the same as a wallet, you have an adddress and a private key associate to it.

I have been reading similar posts like [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/68350/ethereum-wallet-vs-ethereum-account) or [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/68432/what-is-deference-between-wallet-address-and-account-address) but they don't explain the difference between:

1. web3.eth.accounts.create
2. web3.eth.accounts.wallet.create

Are both analogous and give a similar result?

With both I get the same properties:

```
 - address: "0x..."
 - encrypt: function encrypt(r, n) 
 - privateKey: "..."
 - sign: function sign(r)​ 
 - signTransaction: function signTransaction(r, n)
```

Answer (score 0):

`web3js` defines a `wallet` as a set of public/private key pairs, or, in other words, a set of EOAs.

`web3.eth.accounts.create` allows to generate a single EOA whereas `web3.eth.accounts.wallet.create` enables the creation of multiple accounts.

For example :

```
//create two EOAs
const wallet = web3.eth.accounts.wallet.create(2, 'test');
//get first account properties
account_1 = wallet[0];
//get second account properties
account_2 = wallet[1];
// get first account private key
privateKey_1 = account_1.privateKey;
//get second account address
address_2 = account_2.address;
```